# A custom Oracle XE data directory location to retrieve my tables data across docker container restarts

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose, oracle-xe

Using the Docker Oracle XE image `https://hub.docker.com/r/wnameless/oracle-xe-11g/` I created a `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  oracle-xe:
    image: wnameless/oracle-xe-11g:16.04
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
      - "8084:8080"
    networks:
      - oracle
    environment:
      - ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true
      - ORACLE_DISABLE_ASYNCH_IO=true
      - ORACLE_ENABLE_XDB=true
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/oracle/volumes/oracle-xe/config/oratab:/etc/oratab"
      -    version: "3"
services:
  oracle-xe:
    image: wnameless/oracle-xe-11g:16.04
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
      - "8084:8080"
    networks:
      - oracle
    environment:
      - ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true
      - ORACLE_DISABLE_ASYNCH_IO=true
      - ORACLE_ENABLE_XDB=true
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/oracle/volumes/oracle-xe/config/oratab:/etc/oratab"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/oracle/volumes/oracle-xe/config/tnsnames.ora:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/tnsnames.ora"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/oracle/volumes/oracle-xe/data:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/data"
networks:
  oracle: "~/dev/docker/projects/oracle/volumes/oracle-xe/config/tnsnames.ora:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/tnsnames.ora"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/oracle/volumes/oracle-xe/data:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/data"
networks:
  oracle:
```

I can start a container with the command:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose-swarm-dev.yml oracle
```

and stop it with the command:

```
docker stack rm oracle
```

I can then connect from the Docker host:

```
sqlplus system/oracle@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=127.0.0.1)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)))
```

Once logged in I can create the tablespaces and a user with his grants:

```
create tablespace useraccounttest datafile '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/data/useraccounttest.dbf' size 10M autoextend on;
create temporary tablespace useraccounttest_temp tempfile '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/data/useraccounttest_temp.dbf' size 5M autoextend on;
create user useraccounttest identified by mypassword default tablespace useraccounttest temporary tablespace useraccounttest_temp;
grant resource to useraccounttest;
grant connect to useraccounttest;
grant create view to useraccounttest;
grant create session to useraccounttest;
grant create sequence to useraccounttest;
grant create table to useraccounttest;
grant unlimited tablespace to useraccounttest;
revoke unlimited tablespace from useraccounttest;
```

And I can see the data files created on my host thanks to the mapped volume:

```
$ ll ~/dev/docker/projects/oracle/volumes/oracle-xe/data/
total 12M
-rw-r----- 1 stephane  11M juil.  2 14:35 useraccounttest.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 stephane 5,1M juil.  2 14:35 useraccounttest_temp.dbf
```

With the user created I can then connect using this new user:

```
$ sqlplus useraccounttest/mypassword@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=127.0.0.1)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)))

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Mon Jul 2 14:57:21 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

But if I now stop the container, and then start the container, and try to connect with the above command, I get a message stating that the user is unknown:

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Now, if I log in as the system user, I try the following commands, it feels like the tablespace cannot be created because it already exists, but at the same time it is unusable:

```
SQL> create user useraccounttest identified by mypassword default tablespace useraccounttest temporary tablespace useraccounttest_temp;
create user useraccounttest identified by mypassword default tablespace useraccounttest temporary tablespace useraccounttest_temp
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'USERACCOUNTTEST' does not exist


SQL> create tablespace useraccounttest datafile '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/data/useraccounttest.dbf' size 10M autoextend on;
create tablespace useraccounttest datafile '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/data/useraccounttest.dbf' size 10M autoextend on
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file
'/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/data/useraccounttest.dbf'
ORA-27038: created file already exists
Additional information: 1


SQL> 
SQL> create temporary tablespace useraccounttest_temp tempfile '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/data/useraccounttest_temp.dbf' size 5M autoextend on;
create user useraccounttest identified by mypassword default tablespace useraccounttest temporary tablespace useraccounttest_temp;create temporary tablespace useraccounttest_temp tempfile '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/data/useraccounttest_temp.dbf' size 5M autoextend on
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file
'/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/data/useraccounttest_temp.dbf'
ORA-27038: created file already exists
Additional information: 1
```